# How to use arrays to access matrix elements?

Tags: python, numpy

I need to change all nans of a matrix to a different value. I can easily get the nan positions using argwhere, but then I am not sure how to access those positions programmatically. Here is my nonworking code:

```
myMatrix = np.array([[3.2,2,float('NaN'),3],[3,1,2,float('NaN')],[3,3,3,3]])

nanPositions = np.argwhere(np.isnan(myMatrix))
maxVal = np.nanmax(abs(myMatrix))
for pos in nanPositions :
    myMatrix[pos] = maxval
```

the problem is that myMatrix[pos] does not accept pos as an array.

Comment: You're setting all nan values to a single value?

Comment: yes, but I'd still like to know the answer in general

Comment: actually, I think I need to set different values. Thanks

Comment: Your question is about indexing though, which I have addressed. That's decoupled from the value you assign to those indices

Comment: `argwhere` is just the transpose of `where`.  `where` gives a tuple of arrays that can be used directly to index all 'found' elements (at once).  `argwhere' is normally used iteratively as you do - addressing one element at a time.

Comment: `pos` doesn't work in your iteration because it's an array, not a tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [54]: arr = np.array([[3.2,2,float('NaN'),3],[3,1,2,float('NaN')],[3,3,3,3]])
    ...: 
In [55]: arr
Out[55]: 
array([[3.2, 2. , nan, 3. ],
       [3. , 1. , 2. , nan],
       [3. , 3. , 3. , 3. ]])
```

Location of the `nan`:

```
In [56]: np.where(np.isnan(arr))
Out[56]: (array([0, 1]), array([2, 3]))
In [57]: np.argwhere(np.isnan(arr))
Out[57]: 
array([[0, 2],
       [1, 3]])
```

`where` produces a tuple of arrays; `argwhere` the same values but as a 2d array

```
In [58]: arr[Out[56]]
Out[58]: array([nan, nan])
In [59]: arr[Out[56]] = [100,200]
In [60]: arr
Out[60]: 
array([[  3.2,   2. , 100. ,   3. ],
       [  3. ,   1. ,   2. , 200. ],
       [  3. ,   3. ,   3. ,   3. ]])
```

The `argwhere` can be used to index individual items:

```
In [72]: for ij in Out[57]:
    ...:     print(arr[tuple(ij)]) 
100.0
200.0
```

The `tuple()` is needed here because `np.array([1,3])` in interpreted as 2 element indexing on the first dimension.

Another way to get that indexing tuple is to use `unpacking`:

```
In [74]: [arr[i,j] for i,j in Out[57]]
Out[74]: [100.0, 200.0]
```

So while `argparse` looks useful, it is trickier to use than plain `where`.

You could, as noted in the other answers, use boolean indexing (I've already modified `arr` so the `isnan` test no longer works):

```
In [75]: arr[arr>10]
Out[75]: array([100., 200.])
```

---

More on indexing with a list or array, and indexing with a tuple:

```
In [77]: arr[[0,0]]      # two copies of row 0
Out[77]: 
array([[  3.2,   2. , 100. ,   3. ],
       [  3.2,   2. , 100. ,   3. ]])
In [78]: arr[(0,0)]      # one element
Out[78]: 3.2

In [79]: arr[np.array([0,0])]         # same as list
Out[79]: 
array([[  3.2,   2. , 100. ,   3. ],
       [  3.2,   2. , 100. ,   3. ]])
In [80]: arr[np.array([0,0]),:]       # making the trailing : explicit
Out[80]: 
array([[  3.2,   2. , 100. ,   3. ],
       [  3.2,   2. , 100. ,   3. ]])
```

Answer (score 2):

The more-efficient way of generating your output has already been covered by [sacul](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52334956/4799172). However, you're incorrectly indexing your 2D matrix in the case where you want to use an array.

At least to me, it's a bit unintuitive, but you need to use:

```
myMatrix[[all_row_indices], [all_column_indices]]
```

The following will give you what you expect:

```
import numpy as np

myMatrix = np.array([[3.2,2,float('NaN'),3],[3,1,2,float('NaN')],[3,3,3,3]])

nanPositions = np.argwhere(np.isnan(myMatrix))
maxVal = np.nanmax(abs(myMatrix))

print(myMatrix[nanPositions[:, 0], nanPositions[:, 1]])
```

You can see more about advanced indexing in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this instead (IIUC):

```
myMatrix[np.isnan(myMatrix)] = np.nanmax(abs(myMatrix))
```

Comment: Would it be faster to use `numpy.absolute`? Can't test but I'd imagine an improvement over a python builtin

Comment: Probably, yes. `np.nanmax(np.absolute(myMatrix))`

Comment: actually, now that I think about it, I'd like to be able to set different values, something like:

`myMatrix[pos] = anotherMatrix[pos]`

Comment: That probably merits another question (as it's quite a different thing), but *if* your two arrays are the same shape, it's easy: `myMatrix[np.isnan(myMatrix)] = anotherMatrix[np.isnan(myMatrix)]`