# Indexing with ndarray in the same way as using tuples

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I'd like to index my `2d-array` using a `1d-array` of size two in the same way a tuple or basic indexing would be used. I have the indices as `np.ndarrays` for convenience when it comes to manipulations, but currently I'm converting them back and forth to tuples.

```
a = np.zeros((5, 5))
ix = np.array([3, 2])

>>> a[3, 2]
0.0
>>> a[(3, 2)]
0.0
>>> a[ix]
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

I've tried it with reshaping the array a bunch of ways, e.g. shapes `(2, 1)` and `(1, 2)`, but no luck. Also couldn't find an entry from [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html).

Is there a way?

Comment: What's the expected output? Could also explain the same?

Comment: @Divakar A single element, zero in this case. As I said, I'd like a similar output as using basic indexing or tuples, both above.

Comment: `a[tuple(ix)]`?

Comment: @coldspeed Yes, that would work.

Comment: [How to use arrays to access matrix elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52334909/how-to-use-arrays-to-access-matrix-elements) had the same problem - using rows of an `argwhere` array to index elements.  `x[i,j]` indexing is implicitly tuple indexing `x[(i,j)]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `ix` as a tuple for indexing, not an array/list, since the latter will specify a selection of rows, rather than a single cell.

So either `a[tuple(ix)]` or `a[(*ix,)]` will work.

Comment: Hm. So the answer is: there is no way to do it?

Comment: @Felix The answer is: you can, but you have to work for it.